# Set teams and rights for multiple git repositories

Tags: github, devops

I have 150 + GitHub repositories and need to add several identical teams for them. Is there any way of doing it automatically not just one by one ? E.G. Add teams of dev with write rights to all 150 repos ?

Comment: You should move the repos to a GitHub organization. You can then create a team of people with access to all repos in the org.

Comment: This is a GitHub thing, not a Git thing: Git has no authentication of its own.